# How to write searchable method for belongs_to assocication using sunspot_rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have two models. one is brand and another is product_detail. brands table has id and name fields and product_details table has fields id, name,price,discount and brand_id.

brand has many product_details and product_detail belongs to brand

brand.rb looks like:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_details
end
```

and product_details.rb looks like

```
class ProductDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :Brand, :dependent=>:destroy
end
```

Am trying to do searching using sunspot rails. I want to search based on brand name and product name with the user entered text. To do this I have written searchable method like this:

```
class ProductDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :brands, :dependent=>:destroy

     searchable do
      text :name
      text :brands do
        brands.map(&:name)
      end
    end
end
```

When i run rake sunspot:reindex

It is throwing an error undefined method map for nil class

If change the code like this

```
class ProductDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :Brand, :dependent=>:destroy

     searchable do
      text :name
      text :Brand do
        brands.map(&:name)
      end
    end
end
```

It is throwing an error undefined method brands for product_detail class

Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
belongs_to :brand, :dependent=>:destroy
```

but are you sure you want to delete the brand whenever you delete a product_detail associated with it?

In any case, the searchable block should then be written as

```
searchable do
  text :name
  text :brand do
    brand.name
  end
end
```

I hope, that helps.

Comment: No i don't want to delete brand when product is deleted. Its my mistake, i had dependent=>destroy in product_details model instead of brand model. I will correct my mistake